# $s$ is integral over $R$, if and only if $R[s]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

I am trying to prove this lemma for a bigger proof that I am working on.

Let $R$ be a subring of the commutative ring $S$ and let $s \in S$. Then $s$ is integral over $R$, if and only if $R[s]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.

I am able to prove that if $s$ is integral over $R$, then $R[s]$ is a finitely generated $R$-module. My problem is showing the reverse implication. Can someone please help me with the reverse implication.

Here $R$ and $S$ are rings with unity.

Comment: It is on any commutative algebra textbook.

Comment: oh really? Do you have any that you could recommend for me to see

Comment: Apply the Cayley-Hamilton theorem to the map $x\mapsto sx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose a basis for $R[s]$, and observe that multiplying each basis element by $s$ yields some linear combination of basis elements. Putting these equations together, you get a singular matrix, so its determinant is $0$. This determinant exhibits $s$ as an integral element over the base ring.